# Translate a Merge statement used in sql server in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, merge

Please support, I had a stored procedure create in sql server database using a Merge statement inside. I would like to use the same stored procedure in a Mysql database. Unfortunatly it seem the Merge funtion not work in MySql. Anybody can help me to do that ? Below my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValiderFacturePharmacie] 
    @numdossierhospi VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    MERGE INTO pharmacie P
    USING (SELECT NumDossHp, SUM(TotalProd) AS Total
         FROM pharmacie WHERE NumDossHp = @numdossierhospi
         GROUP BY NumDossHp) T
    ON (P.NumDossHp = T.NumDossHp)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    P.TotalPharma = T.Total,
    P.Etat ='VALIDE';
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you for your answer ! I solved the issue by using this statement below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ValiderFacturePharmacie`(IN `numdossierhospi` VARCHAR(30))
    NO SQL
UPDATE pharmacies
SET totalpharma = (select SUM(totalprod) from pharmacies where numdosshp = numdossierhospi),
etat = 'FACTURER' 
WHERE numdosshp = numdossierhospi$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is alomst the same

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ValiderFacturePharmacie (
_numdossierhospi VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
UPDATE pharmacie P INNER JOIN
(SELECT NumDossHp, SUM(TotalProd) AS Total
     FROM pharmacie WHERE NumDossHp = _numdossierhospi
     GROUP BY NumDossHp) T
ON (P.NumDossHp = T.NumDossHp)
SET
P.TotalPharma = T.Total,
P.Etat ='VALIDE';
END //
DELIMITER ;
```